# Open a Python File in Notepad++ from a Program

Tags: python, file, io, notepad++

I am trying to replicate IDLE's `alt` + `m` command (open a module in the `sys` path) in Notepad++. I like Notepad++ for editing (rather than IDLE), but this is one feature I cannot find.

When `alt+m` is pressed, I want it to run a program that asks for a module (that's fairly straightforward, so I can do that). My problem is finding the module and then opening it in Notepad++, not simply running the program. In addition, I want it to open in the same instance (same window) in Notepad++, not a new instance.

I've tried this:

```
import os
f = r"D:\my_stuff\Google Drive\Modules\nums.py"
os.startfile(f, 'notepad++.exe')
```

However, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File '_filePath_', line 3, in <module>
    os.startfile(f, 'notepad++.exe')
OSError: [WinError 1155] No application is associated with the specified file for this operation: 'D:\\my_stuff\\Google Drive\\Modules\\nums.py'
```

How can I fix this?

Also, given a string, such as `'nums.py'`, how can I find the full path of it? It's going to be in one of two folders: `'D:\\my_stuff\\Google Drive\\Modules'` or `'C:\\Python27\Lib'` (it could also be in various subfolders in the `'Lib'` folder). Alternatively, I could simply do:

```
try:
    fullPath = r'D:\\my_stuff\\Google Drive\\Modules\\' + f
    # method of opening file in Notepad++
except (IOError, FileNotFoundError):
    fullPath = r'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\' + f
    # open in Notepad++
```

This doesn't account for subfolders and seems rather clunky. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your .py files will be **associated** w/ notepad++ the `os.startfile(f, 'notepad++.exe')` will work for you (see [ftype](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ftype.mspx?mfr=true)).

Unless, you would like to create this association , the following code will open notepad ++ for you:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call([r"c:\Program ...Notepad++.exe", r"D:\my_stuff\Google Drive\Modules\nums.py"])
```

Reference: [`subprocess.call()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)

Comment: Thanks! I needed the second one because I am opening Python (`.py`) files from another Python program. Also, I added a link to the subprocess module.

Comment: Also, do you know how to find the full file path of a file solely given the file name?

Comment: os.path.abspath(path) http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html but please bear in mind that truly _solely_ paths couldn't be resolved , there is no way Python runtime could deduce the full path of foo.txt if its located in several folders

Comment: I tried doing `f = r"nums.py"` and then `p = os.path.abspath(f)`; printing `p` results in: `'C:\\Python33\\nums.py'`, which isn't the actual path of my module (it's in `'my_stuff\Google Drive\Modules\nums.py'`)...

Comment: As I've said :) Python can't guess where it located so the default is Python process working directory "c:\Python33" , I think there is no choice in your situation and you will need to use full paths

Comment: IDLE does it, so I think it's possible somehow. It searches on `sys.path` (that's what it says when I press `alt`+`m`), if that's helpful. My modules are always found doing this in IDLE, so they are always on sys.path somewhere. Is it possible now based off of the fact that the file will be on sys.path?

Comment: You can always search the folders along sys.path or append to it your directories of chice